# Get a parent variable using a function

Tags: php

I am trying to access `$my_var` from within a function, I know I can use a `global $my_var` to do so, but that IMO isn't a good way to do this since if `$my_var` is outside of the `call_user_func` it will use that one instead of the one within. I can't use `use` since the function isn't an anonymous function.

Is there a good way to do this without using a class?

```
call_user_func(function(){

    $my_var = null;

    function myFunc($value1, callable $callback){
        // Access $my_var
    }

});

myFunc('value 1', function(){});
```

Comment: _IMO isn't a good way_ - Nor is it a good idea define a function in that way.

Comment: _Is there a good way to do this without using a class?_ - But WHY?

Comment: this looks very weird to me... maybe it just I am still new to php :(

Comment: to re-iterate: what you are trying to do is not possible in PHP. `named function` and `class` are _always_ declared in `global scope`. i.e. as though written after each other sequentially. Nesting the text  of `named functions`, inside other things,  is useless.  As: PHP just extracts it, deletes it from where it was, and then compiles it separately. Well, consider it working like that.   ;-/

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the use of `$this` to make the code a little more readable. What I am doing works using `global` as long as the value hasn't been defined.

Comment: @RyanVincent Basically I am trying to make wrapper functions for core class operations, and I don't want the end user to have to pass the class to the functions.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways. The simplest is to simply pass `$var` as a parameter, and update it through the function's return value:

```
$var = null;
function foo( $var ) { $var++; }
$var = foo( $var );
```

Another way is to declare the parameter as a reference (`& $var`):

```
$var = null;
function foo( & $var ) { $var++; }
foo( $var );
```

A third way is to use an anonymous function and specify the *use* of the variable:

```
$var = null;
$foo = function() use( & $var ) { $var++; }
$foo();
```